# += vs. =+ in timedelta

Tags: python, datetime

Question: what's up with this?

```
from datetime import timedelta, date
ONE_DAY = timedelta(days=1)
date = date(2015,12,12)
>>> date -= ONE_DAY
>>> date
date(2015,12,11)
>>> date += ONE_DAY
>>> date
date(2015,12,12)
>>> date **=+** ONE_DAY
>>> date
datetime.timedelta(1)
```

Normally, I would expect an error when attempting to use `=+`, but instead I seem to be assigning the timedelta object. Also:

```
>>> TWO_DAYS = timedelta(days=2)
>>> TWO_DAYS
datetime.timedelta(2)
```

...

```
>>> date = date(2015,12,12)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "(stdin)", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: 'datetime.timedelta' object is not callable
>>> date = False
>>> date
False
>>> date = date(2015,12,12)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "(stdin)", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: 'bool' object is not callable
>>> dates = date(2015,12,12)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "(stdin)", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: 'bool' object is not callable
>>> x = date(2015,12,12)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "(stdin)", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: 'bool' object is not callable
```

Apparently my ability to assign variables has also been somehow compromised?

I initially was getting an error from the issue in the first half, and as I dug deeper I realized the things in the second half of my post.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: `=+` is just `=` and `+`, and if you assigned something to `date`, calling `date(anything)` is going to use whatever you just assigned to `date`.

Comment: It's like this: `x = +1`

Comment: Thanks for the comments! I get the whole ("=+" == "= +") issue. I'm really also curious about the 2nd half of the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I see one thing that is wrong here

The first time you do

```
from datetime import timedelta, date
ONE_DAY = timedelta(days=1)
date = date(2015,12,12)
```

You forgot to notice but you just re-assigned the date() to now a specific date

and now when you do another assignment with

```
>>> date = date(2015,12,12)
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "(stdin)", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: 'datetime.timedelta' object is not callable
```

what you essentially did is

```
date(2015,12,12)(2015,12,12) # Obviously makes no sense
```

Just use another variable instead of the `date` and you should be good

Comment: Thanks! Only person who answered the hard part of the question.

Comment: Glad I could help! :)

Answer (score 9):

`=+` is not an augmented assignment syntax. You have `=` and a *separate* [unary `+` operator](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/expressions.html#unary-arithmetic-and-bitwise-operations):

```
date = (+ONE_DAY)
```

You rebound `date` to `ONE_DAY` (`+` did nothing to that value).

Note that you bound the name `date` first to a `datetime.date()` instance, then to a `datetime.timedelta()` instance with the above `=+` statement. You can't then still expect it to be bound to the `datetime.date` object from the `import` line. Python doesn't separate imported names from other names in your code, importing binds names just the same way assignment does.

In other words, assignment hasn't been compromised at all. Quite to the contrary, it is *because* assignment works that you can no longer treat the `date` name as being bound to `datetime.date`.

This works just fine:

```
import datetime
date = datetime.date(2015, 12, 12)
```

because then you bound the name `datetime`, and can still reach the `datetime.date` callable from there.

Comment: Thanks for the comments! I get the whole ("=+" == "= +") issue. I'm really also curious about the 2nd half of the question.